# Определение региона и оператора связи по номеру телефона

Tags: asterisk, freepbx

Необходимо по номеру телефона определять регион и оператора связи. Это нужно для дальнейшего определения способа, которым наиболее выгодно звонить на этот номер. Раньше это можно было делать по коду страны и оператора. Таблицы существуют в интернете. Но теперь это сделать нельзя, т.к. приняли закон о возможности ухода к другому оператору с сохранением номера.

Прошу помочь придумать максимально простой и быстрый алгоритм определения принадлежности номера к оператору.

Дополнительно замечу, что вариант звонить, затем оценивать сколько денег ушло - не годится, т.к. пользователь номера может оператора менять достаточно часто (в историческом масштабе).

Если существует какое-либо API у операторов для решения этой задачи, то будет очень здорово, если на него укажете.

Реализовывать выбор направлений планируем через Dial-plan системы asterisk.

Comment: Но ведь метка "операторы" предназначена для программных операторов, а не сотовой связи xD

Comment: Сдаётся вряд ли кто-то будет прописывать индивидуальные маршруты для каждого отдельного номера. Поэтому вызов в любом случае направляется оператору, за которым закреплён блок номеров. Дальше уж не знаю что будет. Либо сам оператор выполняет переадресацию, либо выдаёт ответ с указанием переадресации на входящую станцию. Так я думаю. Хотя может под это дело придумали глобальную базу и транзитные операторы определяют маршруты по ней?

Comment: Насколько мне рассказали коллеги, сейчас за базу принадлежности номеров операторам отвечает ЦНИИС (Институт связи). Официально он в этом качестве называется вроде бы "оператор базы данных перенесенных абонентских номеров". В ТЕЛЕ2 при роутинге ss7 за этими данными SCP обращается к некоему MNP приложению, которые было специально для них написано где-то в Питере. Более подробно не знаю, надеюсь может эти слова хоть чем-то помогут в поиске API.

Comment: Про астериск ли вообще эта задача? Не, можно, конечно, и им звонки маршрутизировать, но оно больше про Kamailio/OpenSER, на мой взгляд.

Answer (score 4):

> Если существует какое-либо API у операторов для решения этой задачи,
> то будет очень здорово, если на него укажете.

http://mnp.tele2.ru/gateway.php?90000000

http://www.megafon.ru/api/mfn/info?msisdn=90000000

Comment: @gecube работает(у меня нет)? не подкинете номер который проходит проверку.

Comment: @FORTRAN видимо, перестала работать. Времени то прошло сколько!!! Пробуйте другие варианты. Либо еще как вариант могла измениться ссылка или формат передаваемых данных.

Comment: Обновил ссылку.

Answer (score 4):

Нашел решение. Ключевое слово HLR.

HLR Lookup это что-то среднее между Whois и ping, но для телефонных номеров. Существует (как оказалось) множество сервисов, которые позволяют производить проверку номера. Единственный минус, что они все платные.

Например,
https://www.hlr-lookups.com/
https://www.hlrlookup.com/prices
и пр.

Comment: Не всегда. HLR это  Home Location Registry, у каждого оператора свой. Там находятся сведения о всех номерах  данного оператора и м.б. чужих, но уже известных этому. Ранее неизвестный номер (например, только что появившийся в роутинге) в HLR отсутствует. Вообще-то чужие номера там быть не обязаны, активные чужие должны быть в VLR (Visitors Location Register) — временная база данных абонентов, которые находятся в зоне действия определённого центра мобильной коммутации. И из VLR (но это местная штука) есть ссылка на актуальный HLR.

Comment: Тут ключевое слово как раз MNP (mobile number portability)

Answer (score 1):

Вот тут есть API с примерами
https://api.regius.name/ifaces/phone-number/#asterisk
База обновляется часто, но есть некоторые ограничения в бесплатной версии
Удобно, что показывает mnc код оператора, и код региона, а не просто названия

Сервер отдаёт ответ в JSON-формате:
{"phone":"9123332211","company":"ПАО "Мобильные ТелеСистемы"","brand":"МТС","mnc":"01","region":"Кировская обл.","kladr":"43","gibdd":"43","utc":"+3","qty":48,"limit":2000,"answer":"ok"}

и скрипт для астериска (token можно не указывать, если его нет)

```
     #!/usr/local/bin/python3
     import urllib.request, json, sys, pymysql
     token ='98yysa8y8lnkn$27sdskldsk'
     with urllib.request.urlopen("https://api.regius.name/iface/phone-number.php?phone="+sys.argv[1]+"&token="+token) as url:
     data = json.loads(url.read().decode())
     if data['answer'] == 'ok':
         print('EXEC SET message="Calling UTC'+str(data['utc'])+' region '+str(data['kladr'])+' '+str(data['region'])+' '+str(data['brand'])+'"')
     else:
         print('EXEC SET message='+data['answer'])
```

Comment: [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Ссылка не работает, видимо автор больше не поддерживает это апи.