# Юзерскрипт для определения региона по номеру телефона

Tags: javascript, crm, tampermonkey

Есть CRM на работе. Добиться от руководства, чтобы как-то улучшили функционал и юзабилити - дохлый номер. Делаю сама юзерскрипты для Tampermonkey, чтобы было удобней работать. Сейчас нужно сделать, чтобы можно было по номеру телефона в заявке определить регион (и главное, разницу во времени с Московой, звонить клиенту сейчас, или он уже спит). Можно ли как-то с помощью JavaScript со страницы, на которой открыта заявка в CRM отправить куда-нибудь запрос с номером телефона и получить на эту же страницу ответ с регионом и разницей во времени? Здесь же встречала похожий вопрос, и там дали ответ, где код на python, если я правильно поняла. А надо на JavaScript. Подскажите, если возможно такое сделать вообще.
[Вот тот похожий вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/517547/%D0%9E%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%83-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0)

P.S. Нашла "цыганское" решение. Платить за API в данном случае никто не будет, и так работаем там за копейки, чтобы ещё платить за то, чтобы чуть улучшить условия. В общем, нужно было бесплатное решение. Вот что я придумала.
На сайте CRM срабатывает один юзерскрипт. Он добавлет кнопку, которая открывает другой сайт, где у кого-то уже есть такой API. Сайт открывается с телефонным номером в url, и открывшаяся страница сразу выдаёт результат для этого номера - регион, разница с Москвой. На этом втором сайте срабатывает другой юзерскрипт, который копирует выведенный на странице текст в буфер обмена. Первый скрипт закрывает страницу через пять секунд. Вообще, хотела сделать, чтобы закрывал по событию страница загрузилась, но как ни пробовала, не закрывает, только по таймауту. Всё, остаётся активная вкладка с CRM и там остаётся только вставить из буфера в поле комментария.
Всем спасибо за помощь и внимание.

Comment: Не вижу проблем, если вам подходит ответ с того вопроса, берите и переделывайте под себя на JavaScript. Вот вам и функция для отправки запросов и получения ответов: [GM_xmlhttpRequest](https://violentmonkey.github.io/api/gm/#gm_xmlhttprequest). JSON можно сконвертировать в объект с помощью метода глоб. объекта [JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON), с остальным думаю у вас не должно быть проблем.

Comment: Вот такое вот АПИ есть - https://htmlweb.ru/geo/telcod_api_example.php

Comment: @ΝNL993, проблемы, увы, возникли. Начиная с "переделывайте под себя". Моих знаний для этого недостаточно. Но я попросила чат [you.com] (https://you.com/search?q=who+are+you&fromSearchBar=true&tbm=youchat) (наподобие GPT), он переписал на JS. Я вставила его в консоль, и получила ошибку CORS. https://i.imgur.com/9c0n5zp.jpg

Comment: Решение, которое вы в итоге выбрали, конечно, оригинально. Удачи вам в поиском ресурса с дырявым X-Frame-Options

Comment: @Александр, спасибо. Я не просто его выбрала, а уже осуществила. Не знаю, что такое X-Frame-Options, я просто копирую в буфер содержимое соответствующих элементов DOM, блоков, в которые выводится текст.

Answer (score 1):

> Сейчас нужно сделать, чтобы можно было по номеру телефона в заявке определить регион (и главное, разницу во времени с Московой, звонить клиенту сейчас, или он уже спит). Можно ли как-то с помощью JavaScript со страницы, на которой открыта заявка в CRM отправить куда-нибудь запрос с номером телефона и получить на эту же страницу ответ с регионом и разницей во времени?

Как некий пример как такое можно сделать...

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', e => {
  e.preventDefault()
  const t = document.querySelector('input').value
  const url = `https://htmlweb.ru/geo/api.php?telcod=${t}&json&charset=utf-8`
  fetch(url)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(res => {
      //console.log(res)
      const a = [
        res.region.okrug,
        res.region.name,
        'Город ' + res[0].name,
        'Сдвиг от Москвы ' + (res.capital.time_zone - 3),
      ]
      document.querySelector('p').innerHTML = a.join('<br />')
    })
    .catch(console.log)
})
```

```html
<form>
  <label>
    Номер телефона
    <input type='text' />
  </label>
  <button>Информация</button>
</form>
<p></p>
```